# UDP, firewalls, and nats

Tags: networking, udp

I am debugging some code which is using UDP communications. 
My *CLIENT* is behind a NAT and a Firewall.
My Server is an AWS machine on which I opened said UDP ports.
However, part of this protocol involves the server answering my client. Which I expected not to work (NAT & Firewall). To my surprise, my client is recieving packets from the server!

How is this possible? I mean, TCP (over UDP) has a concept of a connection, so I guess that the NATs and routers can associate an incomming UDP packet as a reply to an egress connection. But how (and why) does this work for a pure UDP protocol? Would my NAT/Firewall let in random UDP into my client machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How is this possible?

That's how NAT works. You wrote that the server is **answering** you client. That means that the client initiated the conversation. It doesn't matter that you're using UDP and not TCP. The NAT device still creates an appropriate mapping to let answers trough. Otherwise all UDP would have been broken behind NAT.

> I mean, TCP (over UDP) has a concept of a connection, so I guess that
>   the NATs and routers can associate an incomming UDP packet as a reply
>   to an egress connection. But how (and why) does this work for a pure
>   UDP protocol?

The fact that UDP isn't connection-oriented is irrelevant. Sure, TCP has the concept of sessions, but both have port numbers and that's really all the NAT needs.

> Would my NAT/Firewall let in random UDP into my client machine?

It's not "some random UDP". It's a UDP segment from the same IP and port number that the client sent something to.